# Constraint Layout bugado

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu fiz um aplicativo no Android Studio usando o ConstraintLayout. Depois de finalizado testei em dois aparelhos diferentes, um lenovo Vibe K6 e um Moto G 1a Geração, e em ambos tudo ficava perfeito. Mas quando testei no Samsung Galaxy J2 ficou com uma tela toda errada.

[image: Como era pra ficar]

**Como era pra ter ficado**

[image: Como ficou no j2]

**Como ficou no Samsung Galaxy j2**

O código XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/perfectSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/perfectPlayBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sevenYearsSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sevenYearsPlayBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/deusSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/deusPlayBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/justSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/justPlayBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/canetaSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/canetaPlayBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sevenYearsPlayBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_button_src"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/perfectPlayBtn"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/perfectPlayBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_button_src"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/deusPlayBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_button_src"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sevenYearsPlayBtn"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/justPlayBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_button_src"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/deusPlayBtn"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/canetaPlayBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_button_src"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/justPlayBtn"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_perfect"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/perfectSeekBar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_seven_years"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sevenYearsSeekBar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_deus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/deusSeekBar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_just"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/justSeekBar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_caneta"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/canetaSeekBar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Acho que um ItemAdapter resolveria o seu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente colocar os `TextViews` abaixo dos botões de play (`ImageButtons`), ao invés de abaixo das `SeekBars`. Para isso, em cada `TextView` troque

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/seekBarAcima" />
```

por

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ImageButtonAcima" />
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, realmente ficou perfeito hehe. Mas agora eu gostaria de saber o porquê que ficou assim nesse smartphone especifico e nos outros não?